# When I click on select2 my page scroll Right and bottom

Tags: jquery-select2

I use select2 and bootstrap. Every time I click select2, my page will expand and appear a horizontal and vertical scrollbar.

```
<script>
        $('.select2').select2({
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used this style then problem is solved

```
.select2-container {
        width: auto !important;
        display: block;
    }
```